# Create txt file from batch file with specific date format in it

Tags: date, batch-file

I was trying to use a batch file to create a New Text Document file that would only have 1 single line in it: today's current date in the following format:
YYYY-MM-DD

My batch code so far:

```
SET DT=%date:-=/%
@echo %DT% > "New Text Document.txt"
```

However this brings out the normal date such as DD/MM/YYYY whereas I am looking for the dash sign and reverse date YYYY-MM-DD.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do echo %%c-%%b-%%a> "New Text Document.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reliable method - `%date%` changes depending on machine settings.

```
@echo off
rem The four lines below will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec MS variables in XP Pro and higher.

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "MS=%dt:~15,3%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
>"New Text Document.txt" echo %datestamp%
pause
```

Comment: setting the time variables (`HH`, `Min`, etc.) is unnecessary in this case ;-)